# To host.net core application as Windows Service using Docker

Tags: docker, .net-core

I have implemented an application usign .net core. On deploying this application, it is installed as windows service and can be seen by browsing services.msc (Using command: *.exe action:install)

However, I would like to install/deploy this application using docker.

I have a dockerfile that has an entrypoint statement as below:

`ENTRYPOINT ["*.exe", "action:install"]`

and I am executing the docker build and run commands as below:

`docker build -t proc2 . (image is successfully built)` 
`docker run --name process2 proc2 (error)`

After executing the docker run command, the following error is returned:

> C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error
>   response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
>   container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"*.exe\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

Can you please help me with the same.

Also, please find below the dockerfile:

`FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.0-sdk AS build` 
`WORKDIR /app`

`#copy published` 
`COPY processor ./`

`# make entry point` 
`FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.0-runtime AS final` 
`ENTRYPOINT ["*.exe", "action:install"]`

Thank-you in advance

Comment: Which base image are you using ?

Comment: This is my dockerfile: <br/>


```FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.0-sdk AS build```
```WORKDIR /app```

```#copy published```
```COPY processor ./```

```# make entry point```
```FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.0-runtime AS final```
```ENTRYPOINT ["*.exe", "action:install"]```

Comment: @EnaJain it may be easier if you edit your original question (by clicking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56747040/edit) ), to add details from your base image.

Comment: I have added my dockerfile contents.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are putting your executable in /app during build. Thus when you start your image the entrypoint should be something like /app/bla.exe.

I'd rather not use a wildcard for the entrypoint, since you can only run one command here and trouble starts if there are multiple files matching the wildcard.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, this did not work for me.